# How to avoid re-render when formik select change?

Tags: reactjs, formik

when i change the select value or checkbox,
all formik Fields will be re-render,
how can i avoid it?

this is my sample code
https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-tharp-y1655/

thanks

Comment: I don't think that's possible unfortunately. It seems others have asked the same question: https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/342

Comment: Kamelkent, thank you. I appreciate it